# Protocol delegate is always nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, delegates, xib

I am new to using xib files. So I'm not very clear on how they interact with their parent.

I have a custom view (LoginView) which is created from a xib file. This view also defines a protocol (LoginDelegate). The sole purpose of the delegate is to pass the username and password back to the caller.

I also have a ViewController (LoginVC) which implements this protocol. I am adding the LoginView to this VC.

I verified that I properly set the delegate in VC.viewDidLoad(). The problem is when I try to use the delegate to invoke the protocol method: the delegate is always nil. Somehow it is getting cleared. Here is the UIView:

```
// MARK:- Login Delegate method
// provide a means to pass the user credentials back to the parent
protocol LoginDelegate: AnyObject {
    func getUsernameAndPassword(user: String, pwd: String)
}

class LoginView: UIView, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var user: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnLogin: UIButton!
    var userPlaceholderLabel : UILabel!
    var pwdPlaceholderLabel : UILabel!
    var view: UIView!

    weak var loginDelegate: LoginDelegate?


    // MARK:- internal use only
    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    class func getInstance() -> LoginView {
      let nib = UINib(nibName:"LoginView", bundle:nil)
      let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! LoginView
      return view
    }

    @IBAction func onLoginButtonPress(_ sender: Any) {
        print ("\(#function): Username: \(user.text ?? ""), Password: \(password.text ?? "")")

        self.loginDelegate?.getUsernameAndPassword(user: user.text, pwd: password.text )
    }

    // MARK:- TextView Delegate methods
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {...}  
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {...}
}
```

And the View Controller:

```
class LoginVC: UIViewController, LoginDelegate {

    var isBleScan = true
    @IBOutlet weak var btnToggleBleScan: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let loginSubview = LoginView.getInstance()
        loginSubview.frame = self.view.bounds
        loginSubview.loginDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(loginSubview)
    }

    @IBAction func onToggleScanPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        isBleScan = !isBleScan
        if (isBleScan) {
            btnToggleBleScan.setTitle("Stop Scan", for: UIControl.State.normal)
        } else {
            btnToggleBleScan.setTitle("Start Scan", for: UIControl.State.normal)
        }
    }

    // MARK:- LoginDelegate methods
// METHOD IS NEVER CALLED - DELEGATE IS nil IN THE CALLER
    func getUsernameAndPassword(user: String, pwd: String) {
        let _user = user
        let _pwd = pwd
        print ("\(#function):Username: \(_user), Password: \(_pwd)")        
    }
}
```

The Connections for the Main Storyboard and Child xib, respectively: 
[image: Main Storyboard]
[image: LoginVC (aka Main)]

[image: LoginView xib]
[image: LoginView (aka child)]
I suspect I am not wiring things properly in IB, but I'm unsure. I have found many answers  regarding this problem. I have tried many proposed solutions, but nothing works. I appreciate any input!

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` you aren't initializing your `LoginView` from a xib. You're also not initializing it with a frame. Not sure what button you're tapping but it isn't in the view you're initializing in `viewDidLoad`. You've also got an extra } in your `onLoginButtonPress` function.

Answer (score 1):

Create

```
  class func getInstance() -> LoginView { 
    let nib = UINib(nibName:"LoginView", bundle:nil)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! LoginView
    return view
  }
```

---

then

```
    let loginSubview = LoginView.getInstance()
    loginSubview.frame = self.view.bounds
    loginSubview.loginDelegate = self   // I verified this sets the delegate to an instance of LoginVC
    view.addSubview(loginSubview)
```

Then remove this function `loadViewFromNib`

---

current problem when you do `LoginView()` it creates an instance without it's layout and set the delegate for it but from your `loadViewFromNib` you create another instance with correct layout and add it to that view but this misses delegate assignment hence the top subview of the view you create in the vc has a nil delegate

Comment: thanks for the explanation - it makes perfect sense. I have updated my question to reflect your suggestions.  I am now getting a different error. "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<xx.LoginView> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key password." I have unwired/rewired all Outlets and Actions, but I get the same error. I still suspect the wiring. Should the LoginView delegate be wired to File Owner or the LoginVC? I added a screenshot of connections.